# .net core, google sign in, and jwt cookies

Tags: reactjs, cookies, authentication, asp.net-core

I have a web app that uses Google sign in only as a way of signing in. I generate a jwt and it gets correctly to my app. But then I save the token on localStorage, which I am trying to move away from, so I want to send the token via a cookie.

**Edit (as I was wrong with the root cause)**

My back end properly returns the cookie as can be seen on the first image, when hitting the API's endpoint 'googleLogin'. However, I don't know how to then send that cookie on subsequent requests to my API so it is used to validate the logged user

My back end is .net Core, I generate the jwt there and also send the cookie, then I have set app.UseCookieAuthentication to check for that specific cookie, but it is not sent on subsequent requests so I am not able to authorize the user.

[image: google request, I suppose it's the pop up to log in]

[image: next request from inside my app]

I don't know if it matters but the front end is a SPA using react

Comment: sorry but is not clear what you want to do and what is your problem. what do you mean by `but I don't know how to let the cookie get to my app`?

Comment: @ElmerDantas thanks for your interest. I was doing some more tests and I've seen that I was wrong regarding the google login popup being the problem. Please see my edit

Comment: did U set withcredential in xhr request in order to post the cookie back to your API ?

Comment: @aguafrommars I did. I am using Axios promises and it lets me do so. What I don't know how to do with it is set the header ```credentials: same-origin```

Comment: did you try to set your header with `Authorization: Bearer yourJwtToken`?? as you want to do authorized calls in your api, I think that is the better approach.

Comment: @ElmerDantas I currently have that header, but the token is stored on the Local Storage, which I am trying to get away from

Comment: sorry but I didn't get what you want to achieve yet...you can store you cookie on local storage, cookie, session...what is the problem storing, for example using cookies?

Comment: @ElmerDantas, I want to store in a cookie, but it *seems* that the response's Set_Cookie does nothing, so I can see the response has that header using DevTools but I don't get the cookie on the following requests

Comment: @AlejandroB. you'll need to post the code you're using to `login` and to `list`...these two images are not helping figure out your problem. It seems to me you get the access token from google, generate your own, and does not use it anymore.